# Problem 4 Conway. Page 126. Meromorphic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is meromorphic to on $G$ and $\bar{f}:G\to\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ is defined  by $\bar{f}(z)=\infty$ when $z$ is a pole of $f$ and $\bar{f}(z)=f(z)$ otherwise, show that $\bar{f}$ is continuous.

Hi. This problem corresponds to problem 5 in the chapter on singularities. I can't find a similar exercise to demonstrate it. What do you advise going out? Thank you

Comment: Note that the open sets containing $\infty$ are of the form $\{ z | |z| > M \} \cup \{ \infty \}$.

Answer (score 1):

An isolated singularity $z_0$ is a pole of $f$ iff $|f(z) | \to \infty$ as $z \to z_0$. This, together with the fact that poles are isolated gives continuity immediately.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $\Bbb C_\infty\to\Bbb C_\infty$, $z\mapsto \frac1z$ is continuous.

Comment: I must prove that$ \bar{f} $is continuous with the chordal metric?